# Right-align some text to the right edge of the text above?

Tags: html, css

I have some lines of text. I want the last one right-aligned so that the text forms a nice column.

This is the sort of thing I want to achieve:

```
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
"'T is some visiter," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door—
                                 Only this, and nothing more."
```

Can I tell that last line: "right-align yourself to the right edge of the text above you"?

I would really prefer not to have to give the text a width manually (even in `em`s), because I don't want the lines to break if the user resizes or changes fonts.

Comment: do you want everything right aligned?

Comment: No, just the last line. Sorry, the example doesn't really make that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` the element containing the paragraph, `float: left` the content, and `float: right` the last line. The floated container will be as wide as the whole paragraph, so right-floating the last line will cause its right edge to line up with the right edge of the preceding text.

Example:

```
<div style="float: left">
<span style="float: left">
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,<br/>
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,<br/>
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,<br/>
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.<br/>
"'T is some visiter," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door—<br/>
</span>
<span style="float: right; clear: left">Only this, and nothing more."</span>
</div>
```

If you need the whole thing to be centred within *its* parent container, you can set the topmost to `text-align: center` and use `display: inline-block` for the text container. I don't think you need to float it if you use this method:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left">
<span style="float: left">
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,<br/>
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,<br/>
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,<br/>
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.<br/>
"'T is some visiter," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door—<br/>
</span>
<span style="float: right; clear: both">Only this, and nothing more."</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! One last thing - I don't suppose there's a way to centre the whole thing (the containing div)? margins:auto doesn't appear to work - I guess because of the floating.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Updated to suit.